# How to delete a Label in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Didn't really get a specific answer in any similar questions.

```
def addApp():
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File",
                             filetypes=(('Apps','*.exe'), ('All files', '*.*')))
    apps.append(filename)
    print(filename)

    for app in apps:
        label = tk.Label(frame, text=app, bg='#8FC10E')
        label.pack()

    openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Open File", padx=10,
                     pady=1.6, fg="#E8E7E7", bg="#677D30", command=addApp)
    openFile.pack()
```

This is how I defined to add programs from my PC to show in GUI.

```
    deleteApps = tk.Button(root, text="Delete Apps", padx=4,
                           pady=1.6, fg="#E8E7E7", bg="#677D30")
    deleteApps.pack()
```

How can I make this button to do the same, just not to add programs, but to delete them from GUI?

Comment: You can use the [`destroy()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) method to delete widgets.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059974/how-to-delete-or-destroy-label-in-tkinter

Comment: Problem solved, I took a look at that post, but it was complicated. Simple function with label.destroy() solved the problem. Thanks!